# forward traffic from a physical interface to docker 0 -> to docker container eth0

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker, routing

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop with 2 interface cards. I am trying to route traffic from Windows machine to Ubuntu machine's enp6s0 interface. I have connected the Windows machine and Ubuntu 16.04 with an Ethernet cable.

From Ubuntu machine's physical interface, I want to forward the same traffic to docker0(172.17.0.1) and to the docker container(172.17.0.2).

With my current setup, * I have the docker containers with **--network bridge** so that it has 2 interfaces. and eth1 is configured according to ns3 project ip address.

```
root@c246ffcf5054:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12491 (12.4 KB)  TX bytes:1802 (1.8 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:88:5d:61:bd  
          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1066938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1432799 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1169075120 (1.1 GB)  TX bytes:2534973873 (2.5 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12768 (12.7 KB)  TX bytes:12768 (12.7 KB)
```

Ubuntu machine has the below ip addresses.

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fd:06:5f:68  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:fdff:fe06:5f68/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47902 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1342650 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:76227846 (76.2 MB)

enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:26:6f:0a  
          inet addr:192.168.0.16  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:641:481:2020:6a05:caff:fe26:6f0a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe26:6f0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:193989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:109541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:216544575 (216.5 MB)  TX bytes:12131093 (12.1 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fbce0000-fbd00000 

enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:04:1a:76:40  
          inet addr:192.168.100.3  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f66d:4ff:fe1a:7640/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:798388 (798.3 KB)  TX bytes:504172 (504.1 KB)
          Interrupt:18
```

I am able to ping Windows machine from Ubuntu machine and docker container. I am able to ping `docker 0` and docker containers from Windows machine using the below iptable. But when I run tcpdump in the docker conatiner there is not traffic. Can please somebody help me with this? Thank you!

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i enp6s0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1
```

[image]

Comment: The DNAT rule tells to have the packet's destination set to 172.17.0.1: this belongs to the host's network namespace, not a container's, so it won't reach any container: As the DNAT rule sends the packet to the host, it won't go further, unless a docker mechanism then proxies the data on some ports to the container (it wouldn't be routing anymore).

Comment: Just to clarify: 1) you want your ubuntu machine to route packets to the Internet and send duplicates to your two containers (for analysis/logging for instance), or 2) you want all traffic to be forwarded to both docker docker containers, having a) one or both forward them, or b) one forward them to the second one, that forwards it to the Internet?